# Orchard CMS- Why does IUpdateModel not inherit from IDependency? And how can I use IUpdateModel outside of a Controller?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, orchardcms

I have added site settings as a part as defined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708754.aspx. I have also created admin UI screens to update these settings, and a service to consume them.

What I need to do now is extend the command line interface (http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Using-the-command-line-interface) so that these settings can be defined in a recipe. However, I can't figure out how to inject IUpdateModel into the class that inherits from DefaultOrchardCommandHandler.

Do I need to add a registration in my AutoFacRegistraions file for this interface? Or are there any other ways to update a part?

Comment: IUpdateModel is really just a wrapper around ASP MVC model binding. You should be able to access the site settings content item (and therefore your part) from within your commands, so you can avoid IUpdateModel altogether.

Comment: @mdm: Do you mean through IContentManager?

Comment: Yes, you can query for the "Site" content item, or even use `Services.WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<YourPart>()` (where Services is an injected instance of `IOrchardServices`)

Comment: @mdm: yes, you are right, this does work. It was pretty much what I had, but I was trying to call TryUpdateModel with the part. I didn't realise Orchard handled this for us. Thanks for your help.